# text alignment in combo box choices

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX ComboBox with several text choices. It would be nice if the choices used center alignment instead of left alignment, but I haven't figured out how to do this.

Following is a style that I use. I added the clause "-fx-text-alignment:center;" but it had no effect on the placement of the strings in the combobox.

```
    normalStyle = "-fx-font-family:san serif;"
            + "-fx-font-size:12;"
            + "-fx-text-alignment:center;"
            + "-fx-font-weight:normal;";
```

The style is attached to the Combo Box as follows:

```
     cbChoices.setStyle(normalStyle);
```

I'm noticing that the size and the weight of Combo Box entries will respond to changes of the above, but not alignment.

I'd prefer not to add spaces to the beginning of my Strings to get them to line up. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the style on each individual `ListCell` within the `ComboBox`, not on the `ComboBox` itself.

You can do this by providing your own `ListCell` implementation with the `setCellFactory()` method:

```
    // Provide our own ListCells for the ComboBox
    comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

        // We override the updateItem() method
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            // Set the style for this ListCell
            setStyle("-fx-alignment: center");

            // If there is no item for this cell, leave it empty, otherwise show the text
            if (item != null && !empty) {
                setText(item);
            } else {
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

> **Sample Application:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxAlignment extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Simple ComboBox with items
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet");

        // Provide our own ListCells for the ComboBox
        comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

            // We override the updateItem() method
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                // Set the style for this ListCell
                setStyle("-fx-alignment: center");

                // If there is no item for this cell, leave it empty, otherwise show the text
                if (item != null && !empty) {
                    setText(item);
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]